# Eclipselink performs an unexpected insert in a many-to-one relationship

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

I have a very basic relationship between two objects:

```
@Entity  
public class A {  

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)  
  @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", insertable=false, updatable=true)  
  private StatusOfA sa; 

  getter+setter  
}

@Entity  
public class StatusOfA {  

  @Id    
  private long id; 

  @Column  
  private String status;  

  getter+setter  
}
```

There's only a limited set of StatusOfA in DB.
I perform an update on A in a transaction:

```
@TransactionalAttribute
public void updateStatusOfA(long id) {  
  A a = aDao.getAById(123);  
  if(a != null) {  
    a.getStatusOfA().getId();  //just to ensure that the object is loaded from DB
    StatusOfA anotherStatusOfA = statusOfADao.getStatusOfAById(456);  
    a.setStatusOfA(aontherStatusOfA);  
    aDao.saveOrPersistA(a);  
  }  
}
```

The saveOrPersistA method is here merging 'a'.

I expect Eclipselink to perform only an update on 'a' to update the StatusOfA but it's executing a new insert on StatusOfA table. Oracle is then complaining due to a unique contraint violation (the StatusOfA that Eclipselink tries to persist already exists...).
There is no Cascading here so the problem is not there and Hibernate (in JPA2) is behaving as excepted.
In the same project, I already made some more complex relationships and I'm really surprised to see that the relation here in not working.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What does, statusOfADao.getStatusOfAById() do?

Does it use the same persistence context (same transaction and EntityManager)?

You need to use the same EntityManager, as you should not mix objects from different persistence contexts.

What does saveOrPersistA do exactly?  The merge() call should resolve everything correctly, but if you have really messed up objects, it may be difficult to merge everything as you expect.

Are you merging just A, or its status as well?  Try also setting the status to the merged result of the status.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
All daos are sharing the same entity manager. getStatusOfAById performs a query.getSingleResult().
Both objects 'a' and 'anotherStatusOfA' are also attached entities. As far as I understand the persistence mechanism, merge is even not required...

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:** @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

---

**Let's consider the following implementations of statusOfADao.getStatusOfAById(456) :**

***1. returns "proxy" object with just id set:***

```
 return new StatusOfA(456);
```

***2. returns entity in new transaction:***

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();em.getTransaction().begin();
```

StatusOfA o = em.find(StatusOfA.class,456);//em.getReference(StatusOfA.class,456);
em.getTransaction().commit();
return o;

***3. returns detached entity:***

```
    StatusOfA o = em.find(StatusOfA.class,456);//em.getReference(StatusOfA.class,456);
em.detached(o);
return o;
```

***4. returns deserialized-serialized entity:***

```
return ObjectCloner.deepCopy(em.find(StatusOfA.class,456));
```

***5. returns attached entity:***

```
return em.find(StatusOfA.class,456);
```

---

**Conclusions:**

1. *Eclipselink handles only implementation N5 as "expected".*
2. *Hibernate handles all five implementations as "expected".*
3. *No analisys of what behaviour is jpa spec compliant*

Comment: EclipseLink does support references to detached objects, although mixing managed and detached objects is not a recommended thing to do in general.  merge() should be used to resolve detached objects.  The JPA spec I believe allows for references to detached objects only when not cascading persist, otherwise requires an error be thrown.  In general mix references to detached object is not a good idea as the detached object will not reflect that current managed state of the object.